# Making a subview hidden leaves faint shadow on the view

Tags: ios, swift, view, background-color, hidden

I have a vertical stack view, which includes two views. I have matched the background color of the second view with the background color of the main view's background so that when i make it hidden, I expect it to match the main background. However, what I get is a faint area visible on the screen (images shown). Is there any way to remove it?
[image: When the view is visible]
[image: When the view is hidden]

Comment: I was also facing same issue

Comment: you want to collapse the area or change the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change  background color of the stack view and second view to make it transparent

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The background color of the second view does not matter because you set the view to hidden.

What you see here is the background color of the `UIStackView`, so set the background color of the `UIStackView` to `clearColor`.